# How to change the output of the models.ForeignKey in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

How can I change the output of the `models.ForeignKey` field in my below custom field?

Custom field:

```py
class BetterForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):

    def to_python(self, value):
        print('to_python', value)
        return {
            'id': value.id,
            'name_fa': value.name_fa,
            'name_en': value.name_en,
        }

    def get_db_prep_value(self, value, connection, prepared=False):
        print('get_db_prep_value')
        return super().get_db_prep_value(value, connection, prepared)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        print('get_prep_value')
        return super().get_prep_value(value)
```

And used in the below model:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    job_title = BetterForeignKey(JobTitle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to change the output of the below `print(a.job_title)` statement:

```py
>>> a = A.objects.filter(job_title__isnull=False).last()
get_db_prep_value
get_prep_value

>>> print(a.job_title)
Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method on your model as advised in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#some-general-advice):

```
class BetterForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):

    def __str__():
        return 'my nicely printable string representation of the object'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried `__str__` method before, but it's not working :(

Comment: Given this reply and the other answer I'm not sure what you want to achieve. What do you want to use this for in the end?

Comment: I override the `models.ForeignKey` to modifying the output of the field from `str` to `dict`. For example, `print(a.job_title)` returned a string and I want to change that to `dict`.

Comment: In another word, I'm working on a project that is using `models.ForeignKey` in all models. Also, all APIs returned `__str__` of the ForeignKeys to the users. I want to serialize all ForeignKeys without changing all APIs.

Comment: I'm still not sure if I understand your use case tbh. In what cases do you want the `dict` and in what cases do you want the `str`? The problem is that you can't get both, you'd need to switch the type of the field. Even if you use `__repr__` you only get a string representation of the value and not your `dict`. Also I'm pretty sure you'd break a couple of things when you change it. What do you mean by _I want to serialize all ForeignKeys without changing all APIs._? Can't you use a model function to support your business logic?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an annotated field here?

```
from django.db.models import F
a = A.objects.annotate(job_title_name=F("job_title__name")).filter(job_title__isnull=False).last()

print(a.job_title_name)
```

If you change the implementation of the field in the `models.py` it might lead to unknown errors later on.

Comment: I used `A` model in many APIs and I don't want to change the query in all of them. So, I developed a custom field for modifying some behaviors of the `models.ForeignKey`

Comment: I think you will have to modify the query. If you don't, then since `job_title` is a ForeignKey you will have `n+1` queries to the database.
You can handle this at the serializer level also.

Comment: Would you please explain more? I think there is no difference between this solution and your solution in the queries to the database.